# Visual Studio 2013 Git Version Control - SSH Key

Tags: git, visual-studio, ssh-keys, gitlab, visual-studio-2013

I'm very excited that VS 2013 includes built in support for Git, but I'm having some trouble getting it to work correctly. I have authentication set up to my own private installation of Gitlab using an SSH key, but I don't see anywhere in Visual Studio 2013 to specify this SSH key. I also had to put in the global Git settings (name and e-mail) in the IDE, which means it's not actually pulling that information from the global settings I've already set up.

Does anybody have any experience with this? I know the official version was just released, but I'm hoping someone may have figured this out with the RC. Thanks!

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827794/ms-visual-studio-gitolite-or-github-via-ssh)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

2013-10-22: 
SSH not yet supported in Visual Studio Git plugin because libgit2 not yet support SSH.

Comment: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1558 looks like ssh has been merged into libgit2

Comment: but for Windows, you have to add the SSH library yourself, which is unlike zlib, it is not integrated.

Comment: I would like to add that with gitlab you can also just use your gitlab username and password. Worked for me.