# Visual studio 2012 git ssh

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 and trying to use Git which is now integrated. My problem is that the remote server only works with ssh (not https) so I'm not able to push my changes directly from Visual studio. I get "Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error). This transport isn't implemented. Sorry". So I've to use an external tools and push manually my changes.

Is there a way to push my changes with VS? Is there any configuration to make this easier?

Comment: Although this is about Visual Studio 2013, the situation may not have changed [Visual Studio 2013 Git Version Control - SSH Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506846/visual-studio-2013-git-version-control-ssh-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least as of [last year](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2013/10/20/git-network-operations-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx), this feature isn't implemented

> As of this writing, Visual Studio 2013 does not have support for ssh-based remotes. If you have a Git remote that uses SSH and you try to perform a network operation in Visual Studio, you’ll get the message “This transport isn’t implemented. Sorry.” (This message comes from the libgit2 library.) I don’t have a timeline for when support for SSH remotes might be implemented in Visual Studio.

Comment: @SandRock the question asked if there is a way to make it work.  Unfortunately the answer is no, that functionality isn't supported.  [They are working on it though](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3801342-add-support-for-ssh-keys-as-alternate-authenticati)

Comment: @SandRock Do you think that would be helpful given the question states *remote server only works with ssh (not https)*?